# How can I make the background of my dialog in android transparent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to make the background from my dialog transparent. I want the progress bar to be shown in front of my activity. Unfortunately, the background stays always white.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/loading_cont"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loading_dialog_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code where you are initializing your dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

or you can also add this code instead

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new `Drawable Resource file` named `transparent.xml`.

**transparent.xml**

```
<shape 
      android:shape="rectangle"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</shape>
```

Now set `android:background="@drawable/transparent"`

Comment: I tried it. I set android:background="@drawable/transparent" in LinearLayout, Relativelayout and ProgressBar. It still stays white.